# Array conversion?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm really new to javascript, and when trying to achieve the following I stumbled upon some problems. I tried searching the forum - and a problem like this is probably something that has been solved before, but I don't know what to search for. This is also the reason for the extremely creative title:/

Anyhow - this is my current code:

```
var arraylength = 4;
var originalarray = new Array(new Array);
var originalarray = {
    [1, 1, 1, 1]
    [2, 2, 2, 2]
    [3, 3, 3, 3]
    [4, 4, 4, 4]    
}

convertarray(originalarray, arraylength);

function convertarray(originalarray, arraylength){
    var converedtarray = new Array(new Array);
    var temparray = new Array;
    temparray.length = arraylength;

    for (h = 0; h < arraylength; h++) { 
        var temparray  = [];
        var temparray = originalarray[h].split('');

        for (i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
            converedtarray[h][i] = temparray[i];
        }
    }
return convertedarray;
}
```

I am not entirely sure if the code speaks for itself, but this is pseudo for what I want to achieve;

```
originalarray = 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444
converedtarray = 1234, 1324, 1234, 1234
```

Can someone tell me what part I've missed or give me a hint of what I can do?
Because I'm getting "TypeError: undefined is not an object" at this part:

```
converedtarray[h][i] = temparray[i];
```

I am by no means a professional coder - I know the code isn't pretty, but this is more or less the result of trial-and error... More error than trial actually.

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: What do you think `new Array(new Array)` does? Because I think it's nonsense.

Comment: You are trying to set `converedtarray[h][i]` but you havent set `converedtarray[h]` yet

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code. Firstly if you want a `nXn` array you have defined `originalarray` wrong. Second `new Array(new Array)` won't declare an array of array for you if that is what you were thinking. You will need two loops here as you have already figured out the first one for maintaining columns and the second one for rows.

```js
var arraylength = 4;
var originalarray = new Array();
var originalarray = [
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[2, 2, 2, 2],
[3, 3, 3, 3],
[4, 4, 4, 4]    
]

console.log(convertarray(originalarray, arraylength));

function convertarray(originalarray, arraylength){
var converedtarray = new Array();

for (h = 0; h < arraylength; h++) { 
    converedtarray[h] = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
        converedtarray[h].push(originalarray[i][h]);
    }        
}
return converedtarray;
}
```

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```js
var arraylength = 4;
var originalarray = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [2, 2, 2, 2],
  [3, 3, 3, 3],
  [4, 4, 4, 4],  
];

function convertarray(originalarray, arraylength) {
  var result = [];
  for (h = 0; h < arraylength; h++) {
    result.push(
      originalarray.map(function(subarray) {
        return subarray[h];
      })
    );
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(
  convertarray(originalarray, arraylength)
);
```

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question?

Comment: Thank you for this code! I didn't get it to work, but I think it has to do with the "map"-function. Since I am programming for Photoshop, that might be the issue:(

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. `Array.prototype.map` is not available in earlier versions of JavaScript / ECMAScript.